# alfresco sdk authentication bearer with own filter

Tags: authentication, filter, sdk, alfresco, aio

I started using Alfresck SDK (All in one) the latest version. I am trying customise authentication in Alfresco. I configured a new authentication using documentation: [authentication](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-authentication.html) but I want to provide JWT Token base authentication. 
When I try to pass through a http header: Authorization: Bearer mytoken - it is cought by BasicHttpAuthenticatorFactory from child class RemoteUserAuthenticatorFactory and it says that it is not supported.
How to pass my own bearer token and then invoke: public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException method? I does not see documentation for adding new own servlet filters.

Comment: I've got the same problem did you use `Restful Api` ?!?

Comment: I use Alfresco REST API

Comment: in this case you have to add an authentification to your request to first log in after that execute it

Comment: you can use postman to check what i am talking about, do you know postman ?!?

Comment: Yes i know, I added to a request header "authorization: Bearer mytokenhere"

Comment: i think that you have a valide answer it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running a 5.x version (4.something may also work) of Alfresco and your Servlet container supports the Servlet 3 spec (Tomcat 7 shipping with Alfresco 5.x is fine), then you can add a Servlet filter by following the spec - [annotation](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/webfilter-annotation-examples) or [web-fragment](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment) based.

Not quite sure about your scenario, but I added OAuth authentication to Share w/o leveraging the Servlet API. Wired a custom Authentication Component into the chain and added a bunch of tweaks (LoginController etc.) to Share

Comment: WebFilter annotation works properly. May I ask you how you added oauth to resign from the Servlet API? I see that web.xml modification is required but in "alfresco-sdk all in one" there is no web.xml files in project before deploying app.

Comment: I don't use the SDK, but I am quite sure the dev environment should pick up annotations in your classes. Hence, there should be no need to mess with xml descriptors. As I said, not quite sure about your scenario. I did not need the servlet api, the Webscripts API already provided all I needed to deal with http requests/responses.

Comment: Returning back to the subject about own filter. I used Alfresco authenticationUtil bean to set authentication (method setFullyAuthenticatedUser), even though after this operation when I invoke doFilter on the chain the authentication is reset by RepositoryContainer and does not work. Do you have any idea how to persist this authentication from my own filter? Maybe this aproach is inappropriate and would not be working.

Comment: Why not work within the scope of the RepositoryContainer? Why do you need to deal with the Servlet API?